# Edit Permission a role From checked checkbox

Tags: laravel, permissions, edit, roles

I got [Zizaco Entrast](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust/tree/1.0) package installed.

I create access privileges to each role than I did.
Now I want to change the permissions for each role.

How can all permissions a role access and selected cases also revealed ?

For Example :
All Permission :
`post_manager , post_create , post_edit , post_delete , user_manager , user_create`

And permissions Role "owner" is :
`post_manager , post_edit`

now , Edit "owner" permision Via checkbox , for Example :

Add Permission :
[image: img]
<sub>(source: [vbiran.ir](http://up.vbiran.ir/uploads/1845914310035203725_perm-add.png))</sub>

Edit Page For Permission :
[image: img]
<sub>(source: [vbiran.ir](http://up.vbiran.ir/uploads/38084143100351932546_perm-edit.png))</sub>

Comment: add the relevant code and point out what you tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: I added some code formatting and I actually included the images. Feel free to click on the edit button to correct formatting if you wish to do so !